# Where can I see the list of custom URL shortcuts and the URLs each shortcut maps to in Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, url-shortening

I have noticed that my Google Chrome, if I type `li` in the address bar, it'll display http://li.mit.edu/'s content minus the images:

`li`:

[image]

http://li.mit.edu/:

[image]

Where can I see the list of custom URL shortcuts and the URLs each shortcut maps to in Google Chrome?

I don't see any `li` in neither [`hosts` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) nor `chrome://settings/searchEngines`. However I did install some mit.edu certificates I believe in the past.

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and Google Chrome version 81.0.4044.129 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question directly, but I thought I should at least contribute something seeing as how no other responses have been provided thus far!

Included with Chrome (at this time of writing, Chrome 104.0.5112.23 (Official Build) beta (32-bit)), there is an internal page you can navigate to:

`chrome://omnibox`

This page functions as a debug utility for the omnibox (i.e., the URL/address bar).  If you plug in "il" and have the relevant display parameters toggled accordingly, a wealth of information should populate in the lower portion of the screen, **including** the auto-completion relevance and association, and should otherwise enumerate the information you're looking for.  Since this would be specific to your account/machine, you'll have to take a look for yourself and determine whether this sufficiently addresses your OP or not.